# Python Error in Displaying Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

On this Image

[image]

I am trying to apply:

```
from PIL import Image
img0 = PIL.Image.open('Entertainment.jpg')
img0 = np.float32(img0)
showarray(img0/255.0)
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-c181acf634a8> in <module>()
      2 img0 = PIL.Image.open('Entertainment.jpg')
      3 img0 = np.float32(img0)
----> 4 showarray(img0/255.0)

<ipython-input-8-b253b18ff9a7> in showarray(a, fmt)
     11     f = BytesIO()
     12     PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
---> 13     display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
     14 
     15 def visstd(a, s=0.1):

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I can't understand why.

What is not callable here?
How can I just display the image?

Answer (score 2):

The problem may stem from how you've imported the `display()` function. If your import line is:

```
import IPython.display as display
```

then you need to invoke `display.display()` to show the image. For example:

```
import IPython.display as display
my_image = Image.open('something.jpg')
display.display(my_image)
```

If you instead invoke the function as

```
import IPython.display as display
my_image = Image.open('something.jpg')
display(my_image) # INCORRECT
# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

then you will indeed get the **error message** in your original post because `display` is referring to a module, not a function.

Alternatively, if you import the `display()` function in the following manner, your code will work:

```
from IPython.display import display
my_image = Image.open('something.jpg')
display(my_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Image` is a module that you imported

```
from PIL import Image
```

You can't call it

```
Image(data=f.getvalue())
```

There's a show method that may be useful

```
img0 = PIL.Image.open('Entertainment.jpg')
img0.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer, but removing that import also, I get the same error. How to fix it i.e. display the image? The code works here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb but not on my jupyter notebook.

Comment: If you remove the import, then you probably get a different error saying that `Image` isn't defined.

Comment: .show() doesn't work 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'show' . AM I missing anything importtant ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're showarray function is doing, but still, Image is a module and you can't call it. If you want to display the image, see my update. I can't speak for a jupyter notebook

Comment: You've converted it to a Numpy float32 array in between opening and showing. I'm not sure why you need to do that